# Spring properties (property-placeholder) autowiring

Tags: spring, properties, dependency-injection

I have in my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />


<bean id="clientPreferencesManager" class="pl.bildpresse.bildchat2.business.ClientPreferencesManager" >
    <property name="clientApiUrl" value="${clientapi.url}" />     
</bean>
```

Is it possible to do the same by autowire ? Something like :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("${clientapi.url}")
public void setClientApiUrl(String clientApiUrl) {
    this.clientApiUrl = clientApiUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use `@Value`:

```
@Value("${clientapi.url}") 
public void setClientApiUrl(String clientApiUrl) { 
    this.clientApiUrl = clientApiUrl; 
}
```

Comment: true, for spring 3.0, which is the current version. (+1)

Comment: so it's the dollar sign! not a hash. thanks for the tip. javadocs for @Value misled me

Comment: Silly question but where does it get the ${clientapi.url} from??

Comment: @user2441441 from a properties file on the classpath, most likely `application.properties`

Answer (score 8):

It took me some time to understand why it didn't work. I always used a `#` instead of a `$`. I always got the message:

```
EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'secretkey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

Just had to change it from:

```
@Value("#{secretkey}')
```

to

```
@Value('${secretkey}')
```

I hope this saves somebody's time.

Comment: I was blokced by this...this was the fix! Thanks Felix

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Just got it. You need to add @Autowired
Something like:

```
@Autowired
@Value("${clientapi.url}") 
private StringValueResolver resolver;
```

I'm using spring 3.0.0.RELEASE

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For spring 3.0, the correct way is the one shown - using `@Value("${expression}")`

For spring pre-3.0, you can try:

```
@Autowired
private StringValueResolver resolver;
```

There were no context initialization problems here, but I'm not sure it will work. Using the resolver you can resolve properties.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use

```
<context:property-override location="classpath:clientapi.properties" />
```

and then in *clientapi.properties* file

```
clientPreferencesManager.clientApiUrl=http://localhost:8084/ClientAPI/resources/
```

This one is good too