# Spring MVC 3 User Defined Exception handling with User defined View

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc

How to handle user defined exceptions (Custom Exception ex.: "BusinessException") in Spring MVC 3 with custom message  and view name ?

For Example :

If i throw my own exception from Service layer it should be caught and should redirect to specified view with message, the view name may be same or different.

and i want to display message using properties file 
I searched in Google, but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the answer of my question in detailed which i used in my application.
        In this post  i have explained to handle exception in spring appllication at three level's

1.Error with specific code like 404

2.Error in Application

3.Any Exception in Ajax call

### 1.Error with specific code like 404

in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

specify one  controller

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
      @RequestMapping(value="/error")
      public String handlePageNotFoundException(Exception ex,
          HttpServletResponse response) {
     return "error";
      }

}
```

error.jsp at the location specified in View Resolver

```
<span >
            An error has occured, please contact the support team.
</span>
```

### 2.Error in Application

Custome Exception Handler

```
@Component  
public class ExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver{
        @Autowired
        ApplicationContext context;

        @Override
        public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, Exception ex) {

            TestException exception=null;
            if (ex instanceof DataAccessException) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage("SQLException",
                        null, null));
            } else if (ex instanceof SQLException) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage("SQLException",
                        null, null));
            } else if (ex instanceof java.net.UnknownHostException) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage(
                        "UnknownHostException", null, null));
            } else if (ex instanceof IOException) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage("IOException",
                        null,null));
            } else if (ex instanceof Exception) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage("Exception",
                        null, null));
            } else if (ex instanceof Throwable) {
                exception = new TestException(context.getMessage("Throwable",
                        null, null));
            }



            if( isAjax(request) ) {
             return exception.asModelAndView();
           } 
            else
            {  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("TestExceptionPage");

            modelAndView.addObject("exception", exception);
            return modelAndView;
            }
        }
        private boolean isAjax(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
        }





    }
```

Exception Pojo

```
public class TestException extends RuntimeException { 
    private String message;
    public TestException(){}

    public TestException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ModelAndView asModelAndView() {
        MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        return new ModelAndView(jsonView, ImmutableMap.of("error", message));
    }
```

Exception jsp

```
    <h3><span>${exception.message}</span></h3>
```

### 3.Any Exception in Ajax call

Common.js

```
    function isError(data){
    if(typeof data.error == 'undefined')
        {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Sample Ajax call in jsp

```
function customerNameAvail() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'userNameAvail',
      data: ({email : $('#email').val()}),
      success: function(data) {
          if(isError(data))
          {

    if(data=="email already registered"){
     alert('customer Name already exist');
      }
          else{

             alert('customer Name Available');
              }
          }
          else
          {
        alert(data.error);
          }
      }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help for those who are looking for Exception Handling in spring 3.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html)

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="com.example.exception.BusinessException">
                YourView
                    </prop>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `@Component` to catch **all** exceptions by creating a bean with the default [`DispatcherServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) `HANDLER_EXCEPTION_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME` and then add specific objects to a `ModelAndView`.

You can inject properties using [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) (Spring 3.0+) - see [Spring properties (property-placeholder) autowiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882545/spring-properties-property-placeholder-autowiring) for one example.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.*;
import org.springframework.validation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@Component(DispatcherServlet.HANDLER_EXCEPTION_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public class MyHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Value("${property.name}") private String injectedProperty;

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewname");

        if (ex instanceof BusinessException) {
            mav.addObject("injectedProperty", injectedProperty);
        } else (ex instanceof BindException) {
            BindException bindEx = (BindException) ex;
            BindingResult result= bindEx.getBindingResult();

            // add errors from validation to mav
        }

        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is an overtly complicated way of doing what SimpleMappingExceptionResolver does out of the box, without a ladder of instanceofs

Comment: This is still a valid and correct way to do it and certainly does not deserve a downvote. This approach is also much more flexible in terms of adding validation errors and other properties and custom business logic compared to the **very simple** XML configuration. Where is _your_ answer?

Comment: wow didnt mean to offend you. thought a simpler solution is always better!