# autowire boolean primitive from properties file

Tags: spring, autowired

Hi I want to autowire boolean value from properties file have referred following link with maps url
[Spring properties (property-placeholder) autowiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882545/spring-properties-property-placeholder-autowiring)

but I want to auto wire a boolean property, also have referred question **Spring Autowire primitive boolean** [Spring Autowire primitive boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042006/spring-autowire-primitive-boolean)
but that was for bean value and in my case I want to do the same using property value which is dot separated.

`${does.it.allow}`
// which fails and gives String cannot be cast to boolean
`#{does.it.allow}` 
// this gives no bean/property defined with name **does** but I have the correct property file and it proves that container is able to load it because of first error.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't work for me with primitive boolean. But it does with Boolean type.

This is my spring configuration declaration of the properties file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:path/to/file/configuracion.properties" />
```

This is what i have in my properties file:

```
my.property=false
```

And this is my successful service class:

```
...
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
...
    @Value("${my.property}")
    private Boolean nameOfProperty;
...
```

Answer (score 4):

At least from Spring 5 (I didn't test previous versions), you can autowire boolean primitive.

In application properties:

```
my.property=true
```

In your class:

```
@Value("${my.property}")
private boolean myProperty;
```

Comment: You can also autowire wrapped Boolean datatype with Spring 5. Tried in my workspace, works like a charm :)