# Injecting properties with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, code-injection

I'm working with Spring and I want to initiate my service (model) with dependecy injection. My service expects a Propertie object, containing the url, user, password,ssl,sslfactory parameters for the database. I was wondring if this could still be done using dependency injection.

So my constructor looks like this: `Service(Properties propertie)`
Inside my controller I've got a private field service:

```
@Autowired
private Service service;
```

And now I want to inject the right properties in it.

```
<bean id="service" class="service.Service">
        <constructor-arg > 
            <value>?</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>
```

I don't know if it can be done, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using xml only approach?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, what else can I use? (I'm new to Spring)

Comment: Alternatively to xml configuration you could use annotations and @Autowired with <context:annotation-config/> to manage dependencies. Please take a look into spring docs it's nicely written.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring properties (property-placeholder) autowiring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882545/spring-properties-property-placeholder-autowiring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:props.properties" />
```

and then:

```
 @Value("${props.foo}")
 public String foo;
```

It will inject property directly to the field. 
You'll need to use annotation config.

Or if you prefer pure xml then try this:

```
<bean id="service" class="service.Service">
    <constructor-arg > 
        <value>#{props['foo']}</value>
    </constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

Comment: #{props['foo']} , Where does the foo points to? And also, where should my database.properties file be located? Uder web.xml?

Comment: It's points to properties object with id "props" to the property name foo which should be located anywhere in classpath. For instance under WEB-INF/classes folder.
Or in src/resources if you are using maven.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, sorry. I'm reading a bit more and try to get it working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You said #{props['foo']} points to one specific key-value pair from the properties file. But that's not what I want. I want to pass the entire Properties Object to my service, not key-value by key-value. But all the key-value pairs at once. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is by using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.